# Write once, read many mysql field

Tags: mysql

Can you restrict a field from being updated without granting any additional user privileges ?

Basically a value in a row can only be set during an insert statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [update trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) to prevent the value from being updated.

Comment: @ocaso-protal This did the trick

`create trigger blockUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE ON test
for each row begin
set NEW.value = OLD.value;
END`

Comment: +1 dirty dirty hack, but OP did state that he does not want to mess with user privs.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If you [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) only `insert` and `select` privileges. Like:

```
grant select, insert, update(message, time) on hibtest.message to 'worm'@'localhost' identified by 'worm'
```

... this way the user can only update `message` and `time` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql differentiate between insert privileges and update privileges, which would give a user the option to insert, but not update later on.

see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact fit for your question: If you run mysqlisampack on the table, the table will become read-only.

This is good if you have a datawharehouse that is reference only, but not good if you just want to make a "live" column read-only.